# Why won't a Hyper-V VM boot after being converted from VMWare ESXi?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I was using 5nine's converter to move over a VM from VMWare ESXi 4.x to Hyper-V. However, 5nine failed to create the new machine, although it did successfully move all the drives over...so I tried creating a new machine using the moved disks. When I boot it up it says, "Boot failure." Any ideas why? I'm guessing that something needs to be done so that the Hyper-V machine can read the file correctly to boot off of it?

Comment: It is good to know specifically how you converted it, and what operating system the VM runs.  You may also have accidentally switched from BIOS to EFI or the other way around, but it's impossible to say with only this information.

Comment: It is running Windows Server 2008 R2. I believe the issue is that the drive on VMWare was SCSI and on Hyper-V it needs to be IDE to boot off of. Any ideas on how to make it so that the drive will be IDE?

Comment: What?  Why does it need an IDE drive to boot?  You convert it to a Windows 2000 VM or something?

Comment: Erm, chaps, perhaps it has something to do with the fact David is absolutely correct, and that Hyper-V machines [can only boot from VHDs or pass-through disks attached to the virtual IDE interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/12/01/why-hyper-v-cannot-boot-off-of-scsi-disks-and-why-you-should-not-care.aspx). From a performance perspective, it makes no difference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the disk, if you have access to System Center Virtual Machine Manager, you could to a Virtual-to-virtual (V2V) conversion of the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have access to the original VMware virtual disk you could convert it using http://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter I do this often and it works a tret.

Comment: After converting the VMWare virtual disk to vhdx through StarWind software, if it is a Windows 10 machine, be sure to import it into Hyper-V selecting "Generation 2" when asked to "Specify Generation". I was getting the same problem (Boot failure after importing into Hyper-V and the problem was that I was selecting "Generation 1").